# Cloud Service Role fails to restart

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-cloud-services

I am able to successfully deploy my cloud services. I am also able to successfully, delete a cloud deployment and redeploy and all the roles start up without issues, however, when I Stop the service and start it back up again, One of my roles continues to recycle and I get this error and the role continues to recycle:

Recovering role... Application startup task "E:\approot\runinstallers.cmd" failed with exit code 1. [2018-05-08T15:23:12Z] Last exit time: [2018/05/08, 15:23:13.005]. Last exit code: -2147467259. Last startup task error: name - "E:\approot\runinstallers.cmd" , exit code - 1

Recently, the only thing that has changed in the startup task is the registering of a new port using

netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:8443/ sddl=D:(A;;GX;;;NS)

any help in debugging this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to debug:

- Remote desktop to the machine. You will have to enable this and hopefully at the point your worker role is failing, you can already remote desktop to it. From your error message, it looks like you should be able to remote in.
- Check Window’s Event Viewer.
- There may need elevated permission for certain part of your application.
- Set Application Insight to diagnose the service.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to stack247’s suggestions, if it’s the case of missing DLL, to address missing DLL and assembly errors, follow these steps:

1. Open the solution in Visual Studio.
2. In Solution Explorer, open the References folder.
3. Click the assembly identified in the error.
4. In the Properties pane, locate Copy Local property and set the value to True.
5. Redeploy the cloud service.
   Once you have verified that all errors have been corrected, you can deploy the service without checking the Enable IntelliTrace for .NET 4 roles check box.

Common causes why the roles may recycle, you may further narrow down the issue through these steps:

1. Missing runtime dependencies: you must explicitly include that assembly in the application package.
2. Assembly targets wrong platform: Azure is a 64-bit environment. Therefore, .NET assemblies compiled for a 32-bit target won't work on Azure.
3. Role throws unhandled exceptions while initializing or stopping: Any exceptions that are thrown by the methods of the RoleEntryPoint class, which includes the OnStart, OnStop, and Run methods, are unhandled exceptions. If an unhandled exception occurs in one of these methods, the role will recycle.
4. Role returns from Run method: The Run method is intended to run indefinitely. If your code overrides the Run method, it should sleep indefinitely. If the Run method returns, the role recycles.
5. Incorrect DiagnosticsConnectionString setting: If application uses Azure Diagnostics, your service configuration file must specify the DiagnosticsConnectionString configuration setting. This setting should specify an HTTPS connection to your storage account in Azure
6. Exported certificate does not include private key: To run a web role under SSL, you must ensure that your exported management certificate includes the private key.
   Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-troubleshoot-roles-that-fail-start